# How can I update nodejs version in laragon?

Tags: node.js, laragon

I use laragon for many thing. It's an awesome software. However, nodejs version is old. How can I update nodejs version in laragon? 
Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 7):

I got it. All I needed to replace the old version with new version.You need make sure that you are installing the new version in 'C:\laragon\bin\nodejs'. Hope it may helps others.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!

Comment: I am on Windows. We usually install nodejs. do not 'unzip'. How can we do it on windows?

Comment: In addition to this, I had to switch the node version by right clicking the laragon icon in system tray. After that I had to delete the older version from 'C:\laragon\bin\nodejs'. I then reloaded the CMD and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

1. Download **NodeJs** zip from here https://nodejs.org/dist/
2. Extract the zip
3. Copy & Paste **{LARAGON}\bin\nodejs**